# How to add new widget to pdf/widgets flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, plugins, printing, flutter-desktop

I am working on flutter desktop application. I want to print invoice to the printer and for that purpose I am using this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/printing for printing.

Now in designing layout for invoice i want to use plugin widget in pdf widgets view but could not do so. Can anyone tell me how to add widget to pdf/widgets
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFYl5.png). Here is the screenshot of piece of code. this is what i am trying to do.

Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Did you import the DottedLine library, that might be what is wrong with the code but i don't understand your question do you want to display the pdf's and why are you using the DottedLine package

Comment: I imported DottedLine package but the library which i am using for creating invoice layout design use pdf view widgets and these widgets as integrated in the plugin. So that's why i could not use DottedLine package because this plugin is not present in pdf widgets. How can i add so, or any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the custom paint that comes with the pdf package. Extending stateless widget of the pdf package allows you to create your own widgets for the pdf. In the code snippet below I implemented a custom pdf widget that adds a dashed border over a widget(works exactly like the dotted_border package which you can find [here](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border)).

```dart
class DottedBorder extends pw.StatelessWidget {
  final pw.EdgeInsets padding;
  final pw.Widget child;
  final PdfColor color;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final List<double> dashPattern;
  final BorderType borderType;
  final pw.Radius radius;

  DottedBorder({
    required this.child,
    this.padding = const pw.EdgeInsets.all(2),
    this.color = PdfColors.black,
    this.strokeWidth = 1.0,
    this.borderType = BorderType.Rect,
    this.dashPattern = const [3, 1],
    this.radius = const pw.Radius.circular(0),
  });

  @override
  pw.Widget build(pw.Context context) {
    return pw.Stack(
      children: [
        pw.Positioned.fill(
          child: pw.CustomPaint(
            painter: (canvas, size) {
              canvas
                ..setLineWidth(strokeWidth)
                ..setStrokeColor(color)
                ..setLineDashPattern(dashPattern);

              switch (borderType) {
                case BorderType.Circle:
                  _getCirclePath(canvas, size);
                case BorderType.Rect:
                  _getRectPath(canvas, size);
                case BorderType.RRect:
                  _getRRectPath(canvas, size, radius.x);
                case BorderType.Oval:
                  _getOvalPath(canvas, size);
              }

              canvas.strokePath(close: true);
            },
          ),
        ),
        pw.Padding(
          padding: padding,
          child: child,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _getCirclePath(PdfGraphics canvas, PdfPoint size) {
    double w = size.x;
    double h = size.y;
    double s = size.x > size.y ? size.y : size.x;

    canvas.drawRRect(
      w > s ? (w - s) / 2 : 0,
      h > s ? (h - s) / 2 : 0,
      s,
      s,
      s / 2,
      s / 2,
    );
  }

  void _getRRectPath(PdfGraphics canvas, PdfPoint size, double radius) {
    canvas.drawRRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y, radius, radius);
  }

  void _getRectPath(PdfGraphics canvas, PdfPoint size) {
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
  }

  void _getOvalPath(PdfGraphics canvas, PdfPoint size) {
    canvas.drawEllipse(size.x, size.y, 8, 8);
  }
}

/// The different supported BorderTypes
enum BorderType { Circle, RRect, Rect, Oval }
```

It looks like this
[image: example showing dotted border in a pdf preview]

Comment: After raising an issue with the package author concerning this, he pointed out that this has already been implemented and overrode the border style to dashed works to implement this.
Overriding the decoration property of a container gives the same dashed border as the example above

```dart
 pw.BoxDecoration(
     borderRadius: const pw.BorderRadius.all(
         pw.Radius.circular(16),
     ),
     border: pw.Border.all(
        color: PdfColor.fromHex('#46474A'),
        style: const pw.BorderStyle(pattern: [10, 5]),
    ),
),
```